# IP reversing in Python List

Tags: python, list, ip

I am trying to perform IP reversing of IP's in Python List.

For reversing an IP I am converting the items in list to string and doing the same.

But unfortunately I am not getting results as I expected.

Consider the List with IP as follows:

```
['1.3.6.5', '8.9.25.4']
```

Expected reversed result:

```
 ['5.6.3.1', '4.25.9.8']
```

Obtained reversed result:

```
4.25.9.5, 8.6.3.1
```

Here it is my code attached:

```
        ips = [''.join(ip) for ip in ips if ip]

        def reverse(ips):
                if len(ips) <= 1:
                        return ips
                l = ips.split('.')
                return '.'.join(l[::-1])

        ips = str(ips).strip('[]')
        ips = ips.replace("'", "")

        ip_reversed = reverse(ips)
        LOG.info(ip_reversed)
```

Some one let me know how we can fix this, Else someone let me know any easy fix for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list_comprehension. That is,

- iterate over each element
- split according to dot
- Then reverse the obtained list
- Now, join them with dot.

  ```
  >>> s = ['1.3.6.5', '8.9.25.4']
  >>> ['.'.join(i.split('.')[::-1]) for i in s]
  ['5.6.3.1', '4.25.9.8']
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
ipList = ['1.3.6.5', '8.9.25.4' , '192.168.0.125']

for ip in ipList:
  # '192.168.0.125'(ip)=> ['192','168','0','125'](split)=> ['125'.'0'.'168'.'192'](split)[::-1]
  ip_reverse = '.'.join(ip.split('.')[::-1])
  print(ip_reverse)
```